# Queue of functions - Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, segue

I have a table in which each cell there is the profile name of a user. I want that when the profile name is clicked, it will go to the profile page of the user. I created a delegate from the cell for this. But the problem is, the variable "goToProfileVar" is empty at the starting point. Then I assign a value to it with the "goToCell103" function. Then the assigned value should be used in the "prepareforsegue" to pass the username data to the profile page. The problem is that, prepareforseque functions works first and the "goToProfileVar" becomes empty and passed so, then the variable is assigned from the cell.username.text.

How can I queue these functions?

```
 var goToProfileVar = String()
 var goToProfileVar2 = String()

func goToCell103(cell: mainCell)
{
    var goToCell103:mainCell? = cell as mainCell
    var indexPath: NSIndexPath  = self.resultsTable.indexPathForCell(goToCell103!)!

    goToProfileVar = cell.usernameLbl.text!
    goToProfileVar2 = cell.objectid.text!
           println("\(goToProfileVar) first.")
    println("\(goToProfileVar2) first.")



}


override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {



    if (segue.identifier == "goToProfile8") {
        var svc = segue.destinationViewController as! generalProfileLast;
        svc.dataPassed = goToProfileVar}

   else if (segue.identifier == "goToLikers1") {
        var svc = segue.destinationViewController as! likers;
        svc.dataPassed = goToProfileVar2}

    else if (segue.identifier == "goToComments1") {
        var svc = segue.destinationViewController as! enterCommentVC;
        svc.dataPassed = goToProfileVar2}

    else if (segue.identifier == "goToComments2") {
        var svc = segue.destinationViewController as! commenters;
        svc.dataPassed = goToProfileVar2}

      println("\(goToProfileVar) second.")
     println("\(goToProfileVar2) second.")

}
```

Comment: Where are you calling the `performSegue` method? As long as you call `goToCell103` before calling `performSegue` you should be fine.

Comment: it is actually a push segue. Directly from the label to the page.

Comment: Change the segue to a manual segue, and call `performSegueWithIdentifier` after the last line of `goToCell103` and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

It is in general bad approach to use current view state as a model. Likely your UI populated from somewhere, so use the same source of data to initialize your controllers in prepareForSegue.

If you do not want to change a lot of your architecture and still prefer your way you can use goToCell103 right in prepareForSegue with a sender as an input parameter. In a cell segues sender would be a taped cell.

Comment: Hello Nikita, how can I do the "prepareForSegue with a sender as an input parameter" option. By the way, can not the prepareForSeque functions used in the uitableviewCell part of coding, or can it only be used in the uitableview coding part.

Comment: Regarding use of sender in goToCell103 @vacawama code is the right way to go.